# Is there any way to create generic type trait without passing parameters

Tags: scala

I have trait like this I can create pipe objects like Pipe[String,Int], Pipe[String,String],Pipe[(String,Double),String]

```
trait Pipe[In,Out] {
  def apply(rdd: RDD[In]): RDD[Out]
}
```

Is there any way to create trait Pipe like this

```
trait Pipe {
  def apply[In,Out](rdd: RDD[In]): RDD[Out]
}
```

then I can use Pipe objects without giving any parameters.But I couldn't create this trait objects.

Comment: You can use [type members](http://typelevel.org/blog/2015/07/13/type-members-parameters.html), but you'd still have to fill in the types at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I want to create Pipe objects dynamically.Is there any way to do this without specifying types ?

Comment: Dynamically at run time?

Answer (score 0):

In order to produce an `RDD[Out]` from an `RDD[In]` you **need** to know how to transform one into the other. This transformation is what would hold the `Out` parameter, e.g.:

```
trait Pipe[In,Out] {
  def apply(rdd: RDD[In]): RDD[Out] = rddTransformer(rdd)
  private def rddTransformer: RDD[In] => RDD[Out]
}
```

If you know at compile time what `Out` type you want for some `In` types, then look into Functional Dependencies: https://milessabin.com/blog/2011/07/16/fundeps-in-scala/